# Combining `animation` and `play` functions in gloss

Tags: haskell, gloss

I am implementing a simple Simon game using Haskell with Gloss. I wish, at the moment, that, for example, for the first 4 seconds some rectangles will change their color (or simply in other words show some animation), and afterwards allow colors change using specific keyboard keys input.

This is the code, using `animate` for an animation:

```
window :: Display
window = InWindow "Simon" (width, height) (offset, offset)

background :: Color
background = black

data SimonGame = Game {
    rectangleGreen::Picture, 
    rectangleRed::Picture,
    rectangleBlue::Picture,
    rectangleYellow::Picture
} deriving Show

initialState :: SimonGame
initialState = Game
  { rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color green $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
    rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color red $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
    rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color blue $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
    rectangleYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color yellow $ rectangleSolid 60 60
  }

render :: SimonGame -> Picture 
render game = pictures
              [ rectangleGreen game,
                rectangleRed game,
                rectangleBlue game,
                rectangleYellow game
              ]

updateBoard :: Int-> SimonGame -> SimonGame
updateBoard seconds game
  | sec_value == 1 = game {
                              rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color white  $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color red $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color blue $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color yellow $ rectangleSolid 60 60
                          }
  | sec_value == 2 = game {
                              rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color green  $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color white $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color blue $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color yellow $ rectangleSolid 60 60
                          }
  | sec_value == 3 = game {
                              rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color green  $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color red $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color white $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color yellow $ rectangleSolid 60 60
                          }
  | sec_value == 0 = game {
                              rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color green  $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color red $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color blue $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color white $ rectangleSolid 60 60
                          }
  | otherwise = game
  where
    sec_value = (seconds `mod` 4)


main :: IO ()
main = animate window background frame
  where
    frame :: Float -> Picture
    frame seconds = render $ updateBoard (ceiling seconds) initialState
```

I know that using the function `play` i can somehow implement a logic, that using the function i implemented `handleKeys`, that takes users input and changes the game state.

```
handleKeys :: Event -> SimonGame -> SimonGame
handleKeys (EventKey (Char 'a') _ _ _) game = game { rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color white  $ rectangleSolid 60 60 }
handleKeys (EventKey (Char 's') _ _ _) game = game { rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color white $ rectangleSolid 60 60 }
handleKeys (EventKey (Char 'd') _ _ _) game = game { rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color white $ rectangleSolid 60 60 }
handleKeys (EventKey (Char 'f') _ _ _) game = game { rectangleYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color white $ rectangleSolid 60 60 }
handleKeys _ game = game
```

Is there a way to combine the function `play` with the function `animate` so my program will show a short animation and **then** wait for input and act accordingly?

Comment: I seem to recall having made a comment about _repetitive code_... please factor out all that `translate` stuff so the code isn't bloated with needless, maintenance- and reading unfriendly repetition!

Comment: You do not 'combine' `play` and `animate` in any sense - you always use one or the other. You can recover the absolute time since starting the program from a sequence of time deltas by storing the absolute time in the game state (this is a typical solution to this problem.. I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the types of `animate` and `play` (and also `simulate`).
  [docs/Graphics-Gloss](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.11.1.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss.html).
`animate` is a simplified version of `play` where you ignore any inputs, and ignore any previous state of the animation.  So have your input handler check whether your're in the first 4 seconds or not, and have your step function do the same.